# call zxing from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, zxing

I created a activity that use navigation drawer with inner static fragment

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;

            switch (SectionNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movement, container, false);
                    movementActivity = new MovementActivity(context);
                    movementActivity .setUp();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    marketActivity = new MarketActivity(context);
                    marketActivity.loadMarkets(rootView);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
```

my setup function is in movementActivity Activity

```
public void setUp()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

and onActivityResult also in movementActivity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.e("onActivityResult", "1");
            if(requestCode == 0)     {

                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)         {
                    Log.e("onActivityResult", "3");


                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                    Log.e("onActivityResult", "2");
                    Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "
                            +format);

                    // Handle successful scan
                }
                else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                {              // Handle cancel
                    Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
                }
            }
        }
```

the problem is when i call setup function i get this error

```
07-13 05:26:32.803  20962-20962/com.baagmn.routingware E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3204)
        at com.baagmn.routingware.Activities.SettingActivities.MovementActivity.setUp(MovementActivity.java:40)
        at com.baagmn.routingware.Activities.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:164)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

sorry for my bad English and I hope that u understand my problem

Comment: An NPE can't happen in that method. Are you sure you are showing what you compiled and deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you don't have the zxing activity installed on that device.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en

The method you're using requires that both your activity and the standalone zxing activity be installed.  If you want to integrate directly, you'll need a more involved plan.  You can doit, but I don't have that in front of me.

Usually, though, I'd expect a more robust error than an NPE, so I could be wrong.

Comment: No, it would result in `ActivityNotFoundException` if so. this is something else.

Comment: I just ran some tests.  It really has to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to use intents in zxing is by using the IntentIntegrator class - this elegantly handles the case where the Barcode Scanner app isn't installed on the device. To use it, try this in your setUp() method:

```
public void setUp() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

This should avoid a NPE when `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` doesn't exist on the device.